# How do I handle events in a custom control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a custom `ItemsControl` just like that

```
public class MyControl : ItemsControl { }
```

My Template would something like

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" /> 
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now I want to act when either when <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>SPACE</kbd> got pressed so I'd do something like this

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text}">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Space" 
                    Command="{Binding KeyPressedCommand}" 
                    CommandParameter="{x:Static Key.Space}"/>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

But how do I bind it to my Control?

Comment: Where is the `TextBox` defined? You should probably handle your logic in the controll class instead of using key bindings in the view.

Comment: What is the problem to put the snippet with `InputBindings` to the `TextBox` in the `DataTemplate`?

Answer (score 1):

One of ways to solve it is using MVVM pattern and `RelayCommand` class from [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern).

**RelayCommand.cs**

```csharp
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

Then you should set `DataContext` of your Window (or UserControl), it requred for resolving bindings in xaml.

One of ways doing it:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xaml
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Setup `Text` Property and `KeyPressedCommand` from "something like this" example in the `MainViewModel` class.

**MainViewModel.cs**

```csharp
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _text;
    public bool Text
    {
        get => _text;
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Text));
            // Text changed!
        }
    }
    public ICommand KeyPressedCommand => new RelayCommand(obj =>
    {
        if (obj is Key key) {
            // do something here with the 'key' provided by CommandParameter
        }
    });

    public MainViewModel()
    {
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: How can I do that with a `Control` though?

Comment: @suttlcethsexfxeojv maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview?view=netframework-4.8) may help